# How can I repair this detached kitchen sink pipe?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I noticed one of the two kitchen sinks is leaking--that's not really the right word.  It's more like pouring.  When I pour something down that drain it's like I might as well have just dumped whatever it was straight into the cabinet beneath the sink.

I took a look at it and it seems as though the pipe connected to the drain just got detached somehow.  (The house is pretty old, I guess.)  I'm not sure about the best way to fix it, especially since it looks like the part of the nut may have broken off.

[image]

Comment: Your diagnosis on the nut appears correct, it's fractured into two pieces and no longer keeping that joint attached. We may need a photo of the other end of that elbow to give good advice, but your looking at detaching and possibly replacing the elbow to repair this problem.

Comment: Good advice already! If you're really a novice, take some more pictures of the pipes and go to the hardware store and ask the guy. Usually a smaller hardware store with an older guy working there is best, and look at the new parts. He will show you how it goes together. See if you have a large pair of slip joint pliers (channellocks). Sometimes you need 2. Look for some in the bargain bin. You shouldn't need any goop to put on the joints as there are rubber gaskets. It's not difficult at all. "Don't be afraid to ask dumb questions.

Answer (score 1):

Drain lines are pretty easy to work with.  If you are completely unfamiliar but want to do it yourself I would recommend removing all the drain line you can, ideally all the way from the sink to the wall.  If you want to do less of it, remove the portion you plan to replace and leave the rest hanging.

Once removed bring the stuff to your local hardware/big box store and ask someone for assistance getting you what you need.  Pictures may come in handy there as well, make sure you have one of each of the places where pipes connect to something, also helps to have them for reference when putting it all back together.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the elbow, the nut fractured in two and half of it is hanging on the bottom of the pipe. Probably brass and overtightened.

Comment: I did not notice that...but yep you're right.

Comment: So, with a new nut I should be able to patch this up?

Comment: You have to get the nut onto the pipe, which requires detaching the other side since by design the nut is smaller than that flange on the end of the pipe.

Comment: The nut alone could do it yes.  But while you are in there I suggest checking the integrity of the pipes.